# erlang interface to python

Tags: python, erlang

I've been expanding on python version of Armstrong's classical example of interfaces. Everything works fine while I communicate bytes. But, I'd like to communicate long integers and floats. Mabye even (oh, no) strings. Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/epxgDmvu
http://pastebin.com/rD7CWRkz

First of all, all that I know how to send are bytes. Can erlang send anything else to it's inteface? Or do I have to convert float to list of bytes, send it to python and then assemble it back to float in python?

And, the ohter way around: if I pack with 'f' format, erlang recognises that as a list of bytes. Is there a way to persuade erlang to take those bytes as one single float? If not, where can I find out how to convert that erlang list to erlang float?

In case erlang can communicate only bytes, how do you propose that I send a list of integers? If I convert integers to lists of bytes, then I can't send them in one message since reciever won't know where one integer ends and other begins, right? Should I then send integers one by one?

Yes, I am looking into ErlPort and py-interface and some other, but I'd like to start from fundamentals.

Regards,
dijxtra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a low (from programming point of view) level you always send/receive only a bunch of bytes through different external interfaces (pipes, network, files...) independently from a programming language you're using. For example when you work with pipes (which you got calling [open_port/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2)) you send/receive data as a stream of bytes.

To send any useful information through a stream you need to divide it to chunks which usually named messages. Message format define how messages can be extracted from a stream of bytes. For example using [Type-Length-Value (TLV) encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) you can send values of different length marked with a type.

In [ErlPort](http://erlport.org) it all works as following:

- When you call [open_port/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2) you must add option `{packet, N}` so all binary messages sent through this port are preceded by their length, sent in N bytes (Length-Value encoding).
- Before to send a term to the port you must use [term_to_binary/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-1) function which encode Erlang term to a bunch of bytes using [Erlang external term format](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html).
- On Python side when you instantiate [erlproto.Port](https://github.com/hdima/erlport/blob/master/src/erlport/erlproto.py#L86) class you must pass the same `packet` value as you pass to [open_port/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2) (`packet=1` by default).
- [Port.read](https://github.com/hdima/erlport/blob/master/src/erlport/erlproto.py#L124) method first read the length of the message from the stream and then the message body.
- The message body decoded by the [erlterms.decode](https://github.com/hdima/erlport/blob/master/src/erlport/erlterms.py#L85) function.
- When you send a reply using [Port.write](https://github.com/hdima/erlport/blob/master/src/erlport/erlproto.py#L131) method it's first encoded to [Erlang external term format](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html) by [erlterms.encode](https://github.com/hdima/erlport/blob/master/src/erlport/erlterms.py#L237) function.
- Then the encoded chunk prepended by its length sent back to Erlang.
- On Erlang side [binary_to_term/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_term-1) is used to decode the data.

Comment: So, it's only bytes with open_port/2. OK, cool. I've dived into ErlPort and it's realy nice library. Thanks for explanation.